# What is the name of this painting displayed on the Domo's wall in Eternals?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, props, eternals

This painting is on the wall of the Domo in the Marvel film *Eternals* (2021). What is its name?

[image: painting described above]

Comment: This seems perfectly On-topic

Comment: @Valorum I agree. I'm voting to reopen. The community has [changed its stance on "trivia" questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006), and the ["trivia" close reason doesn’t apply anymore](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/1006). On the "identification" close reason, only questions that ask to identify movies and TV shows (and episodes) are considered off-topic here, and [there is *no* community consensus to ban *all* questions that involve identifying something about a movie](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4897/1006).

Comment: @Valorum I've made a meta post about this question: [Why did a moderator keep the question about identifying a painting in Eternals closed?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4931/1006)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [*Der Mönch am Meer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monk_by_the_Sea) (*The Monk by the Sea*) by Caspar David Friedrich.

[image: Der Mönch am Meer]